# There is an error: access is denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

at the moment I am doing a migration of awebsite(vs2003 to vs2010), it was build successfully but everytime I run it on IE8 it returns "There is an error: access is denied". This is the code:

```
$(function() {

            $('#container-1').tabs();
            $('#container-2').tabs(2);
            $('#container-3').tabs({ fxSlide: true });
            $('#container-4').tabs({ fxFade: true, fxSpeed: 'fast' });
            $('#container-5').tabs({ fxSlide: true, fxFade: true, fxSpeed: 'normal' });
            $('#container-6').tabs({
                fxFade: true,
                fxSpeed: 'fast',
                onClick: function() {
                    alert('onClick');
                },
                onHide: function() {
                    alert('onHide');
                },
                onShow: function() {
                    alert('onShow');
                }
            });
            $('#container-7').tabs({ fxAutoHeight: true });
            $('#container-8').tabs({ fxShow: { height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, fxSpeed: 'normal' });
            $('#container-9').tabs({ remote: true });
            $('#container-10').tabs();
            $('#container-11').tabs({ disabled: [3] });

            $('<p><a href="#">Disable third tab<\/a><\/p>').prependTo('#fragment-28').find('a').click(function() {
                $(this).parents('div').eq(1).disableTab(3);
                return false;
            });
            $('<p><a href="#">Activate third tab<\/a><\/p>').prependTo('#fragment-28').find('a').click(function() {
                $(this).parents('div').eq(1).triggerTab(3);
                return false;
            });
            $('<p><a href="#">Enable third tab<\/a><\/p>').prependTo('#fragment-28').find('a').click(function() {
                $(this).parents('div').eq(1).enableTab(3);
                return false;
            });

        });
```

I have checked the show every error in IE8 advanced settings, and so far it gives this information regarding the error:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; Trident/4.0; .NETCLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C;.NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 6 May 2013 02:48:48 UTC


Message: Syntax error
Line: 2
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:1038/HRSystems/login.aspx?  ReturnUrl=%2fHRSystems%2fScripts%2fjquery-1.1.3.1.pack.js


Message: Syntax error
Line: 2
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:1038/HRSystems/login.aspxReturnUrl=%2fHRSystems%2fScripts%2fjquery.history_remote.pack.js
```

login.aspx will successfully run but its empty which is weird, the current website we are using is working fine though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens in other browsers?

Comment: What do you mean SLaks? I havent tried using it in other browser, coz we are required to run it on IE.

Comment: It looks as if your `HRSystems/Scripts` folder is protected, like for authenticated users... because hitting that file is redirecting them to login. Is there something in the web.config for this?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev how to know if the HRSystems/Script folder is protected? So far I can access it because it is within the solution itself. Webconfig is too long though, it has 

    <compilation 
         defaultLanguage="c#"
         debug="true"
    />

    <customErrors 
    mode="RemoteOnly" 

   <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx"/>

Comment: @Ponce there would be a [location element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the web.config. Or possibly in a web.config in the Scripts folder itself.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev There is no location element in the webconfig. There is only 1 web.config for the whole solution

Comment: Another problem now I have encountered is:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 6 May 2013 03:38:48 UTC


    Message: Syntax error
    Line: 2
    Char: 1
    Code: 0
    URI: http://localhost:1038/HRSystems/login.aspxReturnUrl=%2fHRSystems%2fScripts%2fjquery-1.1.3.1.pack.js